# how to repetedly ask for input until a valid input is entered?

Tags: python

i'm absolutley garbage at python 3. this may not be a hard question but ive tried for hours to create a solution to this question and cant make a functioning code. i've used while and if statements.

"As  the  user  enters  passenger  details  such  as  e-ticket  number,  full  name,  and  destination,  the  program validates the user input. If an invalid input is entered,the program displays an appropriate error message and asks the user to  re-enter  invalid  values until each entry is correct"

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible code example, thanks.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and tell us exactly what is not working. SO is not a place to ask for homework solutions.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
   We also expect you to do appropriate research before posting.  Simply searching Stack Overflow for your title brings up the solution.

Answer (score -1):

this is very easy

helle.py

```
while True:
    inputdata = input()

    if inputdata != "valid":
        print("not valid")
    else:
        print("valid")
        break
```

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.  We don't want people to flood Stack Overflow with attempts to cheat on their homework.